# Calculating the product of BigInteger[]

Tags: java, algorithm, biginteger, multiplication

Context: I'm trying to calculate factorials for very large n  using the BigInteger class in Java (for n>100,000) and so far this what I'm doing:

- Produce all primes less than or equal to n using Sieve of Erasthones
- Find to which powers they will be raised.
- Raise all the numbers to the respective powers.
- Use a divide and conquer recursive method to multiply them all.

From the research I've done on the internet, this is asymptotically faster than simply multiplying all k up to n. However I've noticed that the slowest part of my implementation is the part where I multiply all the prime powers. My questions are:

- Is there a faster way to calculate the product of lots of numbers?
- Can my implementation be improved ?

Code:

```
public static BigInteger product(BigInteger[] numbers) {
    if (numbers.length == 0)
        throw new ArithmeticException("There is nothing to multiply!");
    if (numbers.length == 1)
        return numbers[0];
    if (numbers.length == 2)
        return numbers[0].multiply(numbers[1]);

    BigInteger[] part1 = new BigInteger[numbers.length / 2];
    BigInteger[] part2 = new BigInteger[numbers.length - numbers.length / 2];
    System.arraycopy(numbers, 0, part1, 0, numbers.length / 2);
    System.arraycopy(numbers, numbers.length / 2, part2, 0, numbers.length - numbers.length / 2);

    return product(part1).multiply(product(part2));
}
```

- Note that BigInteger uses the karatsuba algorithm for multiplication.
- I know that there are lots of questions about calculating factorials. But mine is about calculating the product of BigIntegers for which there is not much resource. (I've seen someone say "Use Divide and Conquer method", but I don't remember where, and I haven't seen any implementation around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to improve the performance is to do the following:

1. Sort your array of numbers you need to multiply together
2. Create two new lists: `a` and `b`.
3. For each number in the input list that you need to multiply, it is likely to appear more than once. Let's say number `v_i` appears `n_i` times. Then add `v_i` to the `a` `n_i / 2` times (rounded down). If `n_i` is odd, add `v_i` once to `b` as well.
4. To compute the result, do:

```java
BigInteger A = product(a);
BigInteger B = prudoct(b);
return a.multiply(a).multiply(b);
```

To see how it works, consider your input array is [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]. So, there are four 2s and three 3s. Arrays `a` and `b` will correspondingly be

```
a = [2, 2, 3]
b = [3]
```

Then you will recursively call to compute the product of these. Note that we reduced the number of numbers that we want to multiply from 7 to 4, almost by a factor of two. The trick here is that for numbers that occur many times, we can compute the product of only half of them, and then raise it to the power of two. Very similar to how the power of a number can be computed in `O(log n)` time.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that if the product has the same number multiple times, the method can be made more efficient; but isn't just using the pow function better than this? And I'm still not sure of the effects of sorting the list.

Comment: Sorting was to make finding equal elements easier (it then takes just one scan from left to right to group equal elements together), but you can use any other way to achieve that. Regarding the pow, yes, the complexity is the same, but the total number of multiplications is slightly lower with my approach. Consider a case of 8 twos and 8 threes. You'd take 3 multiplications to compute 2^8, 3 multiplications to compute 3^8 and 1 to multiply them together, total of 7. With my approach there will be one multiplication to compute 2 * 3, and three more to raise it to the power 8, total of 4.

Comment: Oh. I see. Like you said, it is similar to multiplying two powers. I will try to implement it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I propose another idea, the pow algorithm is very fast, you can compute the all primes with the exponent, like this:

```
11! -> {2^10, 3^5, 5^2, 7^1, 11^1}
```

You can compute all primes power , and then use divide and conquer to multiply all of them.
The implementation:

```
private static BigInteger divideAndConquer(List<BigInteger> primesExp, int min, int max){
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    if (max - min == 1){
        result = primesExp.get(min);
    } else if (min < max){
        int middle = (max + min)/2;
        result = divideAndConquer(primesExp, min, middle).multiply(divideAndConquer(primesExp, middle, max));
    }
    return result;
}

public static BigInteger factorial(int n) {
    // compute pairs: prime, exp
    List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> primeTimes = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        int sqrt = Math.round((float) Math.sqrt(i));
        int value = i;
        Iterator<Integer> it = primes.iterator();
        int prime = 0;
        while (it.hasNext() && prime <= sqrt && value != 0) {
            prime = it.next();
            int times = 0;
            while (value % prime == 0) {
                value /= prime;
                times++;
            }
            if (times > 0) {
                primeTimes.put(prime, times + primeTimes.get(prime));
            }
        }
        if (value > 1) {
            Integer times = primeTimes.get(value);
            if (times == null) {
                times = 0;
                primes.add(value);
            }
            primeTimes.put(value, times + 1);
        }
    }
    // compute primes power:
    List<BigInteger> primePows = new ArrayList<>(primes.size());
    for (Entry<Integer,Integer> e: primeTimes.entrySet()) {
        primePows.add(new BigInteger(String.valueOf(e.getKey())).pow(e.getValue()));
    }
    // it multiply all of them:
    return divideAndConquer(primePows, 0, primePows.size());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fastest approach :

**Sequence.java**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public final class Sequence {

    private final List<BigInteger> elements;

    private Sequence(List<BigInteger> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
    }

    public List<BigInteger> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    public int size() {
        return elements.size();
    }

    public Sequence subSequence(int startInclusive, int endExclusive) {
        return subSequence(startInclusive, endExclusive, false);
    }

    public Sequence subSequence(int startInclusive, int endExclusive, boolean sync) {
        return Sequence.of(elements.subList(startInclusive, endExclusive), sync);
    }

    public void addLast(BigInteger element) {
        elements.add(element);
    }

    public BigInteger removeLast() {
        return elements.remove(size() - 1);
    }

    public BigInteger sum() {
        return sum(false);
    }

    public BigInteger sum(boolean parallel) {
        return parallel
                ? elements.parallelStream().reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add)
                : elements.stream().reduce(BigInteger.ZERO, BigInteger::add);
    }

    public BigInteger product() {
        return product(false);
    }

    public BigInteger product(boolean parallel) {
        return parallel
                ? elements.parallelStream().reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply)
                : elements.stream().reduce(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::multiply);
    }

    public static Sequence range(int startInclusive, int endExclusive) {
        return range(startInclusive, endExclusive, false);
    }

    public static Sequence range(int startInclusive, int endExclusive, boolean sync) {
        if (startInclusive > endExclusive) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        final List<BigInteger> elements = sync ? Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>()) : new ArrayList<>();
        for (; startInclusive < endExclusive; startInclusive++) {
            elements.add(BigInteger.valueOf(startInclusive));
        }
        return new Sequence(elements);
    }

    public static Sequence of(List<BigInteger> elements) {
        return of(elements, false);
    }

    public static Sequence of(List<BigInteger> elements, boolean sync) {
        return new Sequence(sync ? Collections.synchronizedList(elements) : elements);
    }

    public static Sequence empty() {
        return empty(false);
    }

    public static Sequence empty(boolean sync) {
        return of(new ArrayList<>(), sync);
    }

}
```

**FactorialCalculator.java**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public final class FactorialCalculator {

    private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

    public static BigInteger fact(int n) {
        return fact(n, false);
    }

    public static BigInteger fact(int n, boolean parallel) {
        if (n < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if (n <= 1) {
            return BigInteger.ONE;
        }
        Sequence sequence = Sequence.range(1, n + 1);
        if (!parallel) {
            return sequence.product();
        }
        sequence = parallelCalculate(splitSequence(sequence, CHUNK_SIZE * 2));
        while (sequence.size() > CHUNK_SIZE) {
            sequence = parallelCalculate(splitSequence(sequence, CHUNK_SIZE));
        }
        return sequence.product(true);
    }

    private static List<Sequence> splitSequence(Sequence sequence, int chunkSize) {
        final int size = sequence.size();
        final List<Sequence> subSequences = new LinkedList<>();
        int index = 0, targetIndex;
        while (index < size) {
            targetIndex = Math.min(index + chunkSize, size);
            subSequences.add(sequence.subSequence(index, targetIndex, true));
            index = targetIndex;
        }
        return subSequences;
    }

    private static Sequence parallelCalculate(List<Sequence> sequences) {
        final Sequence result = Sequence.empty(true);
        sequences.parallelStream().map(s -> s.product(true)).forEach(result::addLast);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Test :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // warm up
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        FactorialCalculator.fact(10000);
    }
    int n = 1000000;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    FactorialCalculator.fact(n, true);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.printf("Execution time = %d ms", end - start);
}
```

Result :

```
Execution time = 3066 ms
```

- OS : Win 10 Pro 64-bit
- CPU : Intel Core i7-4700HQ @ 2.40GHz 2.40GHz